# side bar съезжает вниз

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

`side-bar` должен находится справа от основного блока с новостями, но он съезжает вниз, как я понял, из-за отступа справа у основного блока.

Как убрать этот отступ, что бы `side-bar` встал как нужно? (по высоте он должен быть равным основному блоку с новостями)

https://codepen.io/realHikkan/pen/pobQVwO?editors=1100

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. использовать флексы

```
.container {
    display: flex
}
```

2. есть старые способы

использовать inline-block

```
.news, .side-bar{
display: inline-block
vertical-align: top
}
```

или float left

```
.news, .side-bar{
float: left
}
```